# Cumulative Sum if previous row in another column is the same

Tags: dax, powerquery, m

I'm trying to do something that is simple in excel but I need it to be added in my query.  I am trying to create a cumulative sum in a new column of time values in one column if a name column equals a previous row.  Example of before and after below

**Data Input Table**

| ID | Time |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 0.5 |
| E | 1 |
| E | 3 |
| E | 5 |
| F | 2 |
| G | 3 |
| G | 4 |
| H | 1 |

**Table After Query**

| ID | Time | BeforeStart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 |
| B | 3 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| D | 0.5 | 0 |
| E | 1 | 0 |
| E | 3 | 1 |
| E | 5 | 4 |
| F | 2 | 0 |
| G | 3 | 0 |
| G | 4 | 3 |
| H | 1 | 0 |

Basically if column ID equals the row above itself then sum the time and BeforeStart rows above itself, if it doesn't then it is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In powerquery, try below and replace Table2 with the name of your source data table

```
let 
  xFunction = (xTable as table) as table => let
  #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(xTable, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Running Total", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(#"Added Index"[Time],[Index]-1)))
  in  #"Added Custom",

Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Time", type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"data", each  xFunction(_), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Time", "Running Total"}, {"Time", "Running Total"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: not sure if i follow what is going on between your first and second blocks @horseyride

Comment: I guess specficially I'm not sure what the xFunction is doing / supposed to do to help the other part. And which is Table2 in your source that you are referring to?

Comment: Table2 is whatever your source table is named when you bring it into powerquery. Change the name to reflect your version. The function does the cumulative counting

Comment: NIce solution. But note that the ID's already need to be grouped together in the source table. If this is not the case, then the results will be incorrect.

Comment: Not sure what that means. My solution groups by ID. It is not necessary to group in the source table

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2:$A$2,$A2)=1,0,SUMPRODUCT((A2:$A$2=A2)*B2:$B$2)-B2)
```

Comment: sorry if not clear but this is for power query

Comment: I'm sorry bro, for my inexperience :) but if I'm not wrong, excel calculation and power query work with database analysis logic in a way. so I think you need another column that shows sorting. so I think there should be another column that shows the rows in order so you can check the specific row.
After I created an index column with the name "Dizin" according to the example you gave; I suggest you try this:

Comment: CALCULATE(SUM([Time]);FILTER('table';'table'[Dizin]<EARLIER('table'[Dizin]));FILTER('table';'table'[ID]=EARLIER('table'[ID])))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).